# Getting issue in substituting multiple files from sed

Tags: bash

I want to use sed for replacing multiple files from bash script.

When I call it from bash I get below error

DEBUG FLOW:-

```
FILELIST='/tmp/components/ab.sql /tmp/b.sql'
+ SUBSTITUTE_STRING=abc
+ sed -i.bak -e s/abc/xyz/g '/tmp/components/ab.sql /tmp/b.sql': No such file or directory
```

however when I used this command directly on terminal it executes successfully

```
sed -i.bak -e s/abc/xyz/g /tmp/components/ab.sql /tmp/b.sql
```

The difference from terminal and script is of quotes around the file.

I have tried defining File list variable without quotes as well

kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying:

```
FILELIST='/tmp/components/ab.sql /tmp/b.sql'
```

make it an array by saying:

```
FILELIST=(/tmp/components/ab.sql /tmp/b.sql)
```

and while invoking say:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/abc/xyz/g" "${FILELIST[@]}"
```

---

If you look at the debug flow, it'd be evident that the shell parses the filenames as a single token (`'/tmp/components/ab.sql /tmp/b.sql'`) which causes the `No such file or directory` error.